# error in excuting this piece of code

Tags: c#

```
#region Receiving
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = serial.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
    serial.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
    int length = buffer.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 8)
    {
        if (length - i >= 8)
        {
            definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, i);
            Console.Write(definition.buffering.ToString());
            //Int64 val = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, i);
            foreach (var item in buffer)
            {
                SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dBConnectionString);
                //open connection to database
                try
                {
                    string itemcode = item.ToString();
                    sqliteCon.Open();
                    string Query = "insert into EmployeeList (empID,Name,surname,Age) values('" + itemcode + "','" + itemcode + "','" + itemcode + "','" + itemcode + "')";
                    SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
                    createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
                    sqliteCon.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                } 
                Console.Write(item.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // invalid (last) part.
        }
    }
    //definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);


    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(definition.buffering);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();


}
#endregion
```

Edited one. I tried sending 0xFF but the display in console is 0 for this code.

Hi. I have this code and after executing it, I have a problem with regards to this:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 

Additional information: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
```

and it is point in this line:

```
definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error sounds pretty informative to me. What's the length of `buffer`?

Comment: So the name of the employee is just a byte in the byte buffer? Are you sure you want to iterate over all the bytes you received over the serial port?

Answer (score 4):

I think your buffer's length is not (at least) 8.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> Returns a 64-bit signed integer converted from **eight bytes** at a specified position in a byte array.

You get a `ArgumentException` when:

> startIndex is greater than or equal to the length of value minus 7, and is less than or equal to the length of value minus 1.

Before calling the `BitConverter.ToInt64` method you should check that

```
serial.BytesToRead.Length >= 8
```

To go through all bytes try this:

```
int length = buffer.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 8)
{
    if (length - i >= 8)
    {
        Int64 val = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, i);
    }
    else
    {
        // invalid (last) part.
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah. maybe that is the problem. But if it is greater than 8, how can I split the 16 bits to 8 bits?

Comment: what should be in the else? if ever I have a 16 bits? how can I extract the 2 bytes and stored in buffer[0] and buffer[1]

Comment: @iaskyou: The code does this for you. In the first branch of the `if` you have to process every `Int64`. In the `else` there are only bad results (when you have 20 bytes for example, you have 4 too much)

Comment: how about this one? definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0); where can I put this?

Comment: Int64 val = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, i);

-so this one is my definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);?
-Can I change it to definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, i); instead?

Comment: it is not working. I send a 0xFF which is a 255, and the output in console is 0.

Comment: @iaskyou: I see, it works fine for me. (I did notice I missed a `=` at `>=` (see the update). Please check your code with the values provided here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.BitConverter.ToInt64);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: @iaskyou: I am not sure what the problem is. The `BitConverter.ToInt64` works here as documented. Maybe it is useful to post a new question for this specific problem.

Comment: @iaskyou: did you succeed in finding a solution?

Comment: nope. still, this will be an error: Variables.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0); . I want to wait for a buffer to be full before executing this one. how is that possible?